# ASP.Net MVC code first. How force a get only attrubute to be stored on db?

Tags: c#, database, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

The fallowing attribute is defined on a POCO class.

```
public int total { get{ return sub_total_1 + sub_total_2; }}
```

when a new migration is added this attribute is not created nor stored on the table.

I tried to add [Column("Total")] annotation without success.

Is possible to make this attribute to be stored on db as a "cache" for future queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF to be able to monitor a property, it needs to have a public (1) getter and setter.

For something like what you're doing, unless you need it in the database for some operations there, you're fine just leaving it as a readonly property in your Poco class. The operation of adding two integers together is not at all a performance worry, and would probably be slower to push and pull from the database.

(1) The setter can be `protected internal` if you want it to be "read only" except for the database.

As an example of how to do store that value in the database for caching purposes, you can do something like this:

```
private int? total;
public int Total
{
    get
    {
        return total ?? sub_total_1 + sub_total_2;
    }
    protected internal set
    {
        total = value;
    }
}
```

In this example, the new `private total` variable will store what is in the database. It is nullable so that if it isn't retrieved from the database, you default to the summation of `sub_total_1` and `sub_total_2`. You can find another way around this check in the event that the sub properties have been updated after it was retrieved from the database, but this is a good start for what you're doing.

Comment: those two integers sum was a simple exemple. in this case the task is a little more complex. That is why i would like to cache it.

Comment: However, db operations seems to be slower than any calculation here

Comment: If you're able to provide your direct example, then that could help. However, giving it a `public get`, and `protected internal set` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you please write an example?